# Quadratic Equation - do not understand compiler error

Tags: c

so I am trying to make a C Program that solves a quadratic equation. I first wrote it from scratch, but it showed the same errors, so I made some changes to it from a C Programming book. Here is the result:

```
/*
Solves any quadratic formula.
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
 float a, b, c, rt1= 0, rt2=0, discrim;
 clrscr();
 printf("Welcome to the Quadratic Equation Solver!");
 getch();
 printf("\nYour quadratic formula should be of the form a(x*x)+bx+c = 0");
 printf("\nPlease enter a\'s value:");
 scanf("%f", &a);
 printf("Great! Now enter b\'s value:");
 scanf("%f", &b);
 printf("One more to go! Enter c\'s value:");
 scanf("%f", &c);
 discrim = b*b - 4*a*c;
 if (discrim < 0)
  printf("\nThe roots are imaginary.");
 else
 {
  rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
  rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
  printf("\nThe roots have been calculated.");
  getch();
  printf("\nThe roots are:\nRoot 1:%f\nRoot 2:%f",rt1, rt2);
  getch();
  printf("\nThank you!");
  getch();
 }
}
```

Comment: what are the errors ?

Comment: Are the errors secret?

Comment: I'm going to throw out a wild guess that it's not a compile error, but a linker error because you're not linking against the math library

Comment: @Mike Or a compiler error related to the use of good ol' non-standard `clrscr()`.

Comment: But [we close all the typo questions anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions), so it doesn't matter.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; use `int main(void)` and burn whatever textbook told you that `void main()` is correct.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm using TurboC2 to write my code and the error that shows is Expression Syntax in Function Main in the else part of the if loop where rt1 and rt2 are assigned their values.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what's wrong.  Each of those expressions is missing a parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some parenthesis here:

```
rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
```

It should look like this:

```
rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim))/(2.0*a);
rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim))/(2.0*a);
```

You may take a look to compiler warnings. My one (g++) prints something like this:

```
file.c:24:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

24 is a line number where you should check for an error and 36 is a column number in this line.

Comment: @OP: Remember also that your compiler is just a compiler.  It knows whether your code is syntactically correct, but has no idea if it's doing what you want it to.  it's just blindly following directions.  Thus, the compiler will be able to tell you what's wrong with your code, but not how to change it to make it correct.

Answer (score 2):

Well for a start you have some mismatched parentheses here:

```
 rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
 rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
```

You need to change these lines to:

```
 rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim))/(2.0*a);
 rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim))/(2.0*a);
                        ^^^^
```

Your compiler probably gave you error messages for these lines, e.g.

```
foo.c:25: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
```

Looking at the error message carefully and studying line 25 would have told you that you were missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

```
  rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
  rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim)/(2.0*a);
                          ^
```

You are missing the right closing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding in gcc use the below code and link with math library

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
 float a, b, c, rt1= 0, rt2=0, discrim;
 //clrscr();
 printf("Welcome to the Quadratic Equation Solver!");
 //getch();
 printf("\nYour quadratic formula should be of the form a(x*x)+bx+c = 0");
 printf("\nPlease enter a\'s value:");
 scanf("%f", &a);
 printf("Great! Now enter b\'s value:");
 scanf("%f", &b);
 printf("One more to go! Enter c\'s value:");
 scanf("%f", &c);
 discrim = b*b - 4*a*c;
 if (discrim < 0)
  printf("\nThe roots are imaginary.");
 else
 {
  rt1 = (-b + sqrt(discrim))/(2.0*a);
  rt2 = (-b - sqrt(discrim))/(2.0*a);
  printf("\nThe roots have been calculated.");
  // getch();
  printf("\nThe roots are:\nRoot 1:%f\nRoot 2:%f",rt1, rt2);
  // getch();
  printf("\nThank you!");
  //getch();
 }
}
```

and compile this way

```
gcc example.c -o example -lm
```

Comment: Your indentation is nasty.  Also, just adding extra )'s at the end of the line until it compiles does not yield the correct solution.

Comment: sorry for the same will edit it